# Passing a csv file as a parameter to a REST Api in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, axios

I'm working on parsing a csv file and get data from it using **reactjs** and **RestAPI**.
First I have added a input form in my webpage using reactstrap.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, Label, Input } from "reactstrap";

export default function UploadParseCsv(props) {
    //posting the csv file to api, for data parsing
  var bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append("csv_file", csv_file);

  axios({
    method: "post",
    URL: "api_url",
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      //handle success
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      //handle error
      console.log(response);
    });

   return(
     <div>
       <FormGroup>
          <Input type="file" name="file" id="exampleFile" />
        </FormGroup>
     </div> 
)
}
```

This is how my current code looks like.
I want to select a CSV file and pass it to the API for parsing.
I'm having trouble in triggering the post request in Axios as soon as the file gets uploaded.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple I had to write a function to pass the csv file as a formdata here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, Label, Input } from "reactstrap";

function UploadParseCsv(props) {
    //posting the csv file to api, for data parsing
  const fileHandler = (event) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("csvFile", event.target.files[0]);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "myurl",
      data: formData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
      });
  };

   return(
     <div>
       <FormGroup>
          <Input 
          type="file"
          name="file" 
          id="exampleFile" 
          onChange={(e) => fileHandler(e)}/>
        </FormGroup>
     </div> 
)
}
```